# How can I best isolate 2 different unlabeled pieces of html using beautiful soup to be printed to a CSV?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, scrape

To preface, I'm a python beginner and this is my first time using BeautifulSoup. Any input is greatly appreciated.

I'm attempting to scrape all the company names and email addresses from [this site](http://www.indiainfoline.com/Markets/Company/A.aspx). There are 3 layers of links to crawl through (Alphabetized pagination list -> Company list by letter -> Company detail page) and I'd subsequently print them to a csv.

So far, I've been able to isolate the alphabetized list of links with the code below, but I'm stuck when attempting to isolate the different company pages and then extracting the name/email from unlabeled html.

```
import re
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.indiainfoline.com/Markets/Company/A.aspx').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()

pattern = re.compile(r'^\/Markets\/Company\/\D\.aspx$')

all_links = []
navigation_links = []
root = "http://www.indiainfoline.com/"

# Finding all links
for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    all_links.append(anchor['href'])
# Isolate links matching regex
for link in all_links:
    if re.match(pattern, link):
        navigation_links.append(root + re.match(pattern, link).group(0))
navigation_links = list(set(navigation_links))

company_pages = []
for page in navigation_links:
    for anchor in soup.findAll('table', id='AlphaQuotes1_Rep_quote')              [0].findAll('a',href=True):
        company_pages.append(root + anchor['href'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pieces. Getting the links to each individual company is easy:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('http://www.indiainfoline.com/Markets/Company/A.aspx').text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)

# find the links to companies
company_menu = bs.find("div",{'style':'padding-left:5px'})
# print all companies links
companies = company_menu.find_all('a')
for company in companies:
    print company['href']
```

Second, get the companies names:

```
for company in companies:
    print company.getText().strip()
```

Third, emails is a little more complicated, but you can use regex here, so in a independent company page, do the following:

```
import re
# example company page
html = requests.get('http://www.indiainfoline.com/Markets/Company/Adani-Power-Ltd/533096').text
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile("mailto:([A-Za-z0-9.\-+]+@[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4})")
re.findall(EMAIL_REGEX, html)
# and there you got a list of found emails
...
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful! I kept trying to pull the emails by using the table number/order, but that could become a problem if they ever changed the site.